# C++-17: cast function pointer to function with different argument pointer type

Tags: c++, c++17, function-pointers

I have a legacy C-API which provides callbacks for asyncrounous operations.
Since this library requires many compiler flags, is full of macros and the header generates tons of warnings when included, I decided to create a wrapper for this library that encapsulates the proprietary C-library.

But since this library is asyncronous, it provides callback functions. 
The problem is, that the callback requires a pointer to a struct (`X_leg`).
But since this struct is part of the old API and I don't want to include the struct, 
I decided to create a struct with the same layout `X_wrp`.
In the main() I ensure that the size of both structs is equal.

My question is now:
Is it safe to `reinterpret_cast` the wrapper function pointer of type `func_wrp` to the legacy function pointer with type `func_leg`?
Or is it undefined behavior in C++17?

I have the following minimal working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

//begin of wrapper decls
struct X_wrp {
    std::uint32_t member;
};

using func_wrp = void (*)(const X_wrp* arg);

void caller_wrp(func_wrp func);
//end of wrapper decls

//Legacy C-Code
typedef struct {
    std::uint32_t member;
} X_leg;

typedef void (*func_leg)(const X_leg* arg);

void caller_leg(func_leg func) {
    static X_leg inst{10};
    func(&inst);
}
//End of Legacy C-Code

void callback(const X_wrp* arg) {
    std::cout << arg->member << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    static_assert(sizeof(X_leg)==sizeof(X_wrp));//ensures that there is no oops
    caller_wrp(callback);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

//begin of wrapper implementations
void caller_wrp(func_wrp func) {
    caller_leg(reinterpret_cast<func_leg>(func)); //is this cast safe?

}
//end of wrapper implementations
```

Comment: Pedantically, break strict aliasing rule at least, leading to UB.

Comment: Could you create a proxy instead? meaning the wrapper object contains the `X_leg` and can delegate calls to  the old API making the old struct and API invisible but without the potential layout issues.

Comment: As hack (as you might have ODR violation as soon as definition/Token differ), you may copy/paste `X_leg` definition in your wrapper header.

Comment: @Scis: what exactly do you mean by creating a wrapper object?

Comment: @Jarod42, yeah this hack is what I want to prevent. but its maybe the last possibility

Comment: @byteunit Instead of `X_wrp` being "the same" as `X_leg` it would have an `X_leg` as a private member.

Comment: @Scis: ok, that's clear, but I don't understand how this would help me, as the callback still gives back a pointer to the legacy struct und and not to the new struct.

Comment: @byteunit when receiving a callback from the user, get one that expects the new format, but internally have that callback bound to a "private" callback that would adhere to the legacy signature with a simple body that just creates the new object/ and calls whatever callback that was bound to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not safe and is explicitly called out as undefined behavior in [[expr.call]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.call#6)

> Calling a function through an expression whose function type is different from the function type of the called function's definition results in undefined behavior.

This is also reinforced in the `reinterpret_cast` documentation about function pointer conversions  [[expr.reinterpret.cast]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.reinterpret.cast#6)

> A function pointer can be explicitly converted to a function pointer of a different type. [ Note: The effect of calling a function through a pointer to a function type ([dcl.fct]) that is not the same as the type used in the definition of the function is undefined ([expr.call]). — end note ] Except that converting a prvalue of type “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer to T2” (where T1 and T2 are function types) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value, the result of such a pointer conversion is unspecified. [ Note: See also [conv.ptr] for more details of pointer conversions. — end note ]

Comment: I dont understand what would be the prvalue of a function pointer.

Comment: @user13947194 A function like `void(*)(void) get_fptr() { .... }` returns a prvalue of type pointer to `void(void)`

Comment: So when do prvalues of function pointers able to be the same? I am assuming the text was hinting at that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with [NathanOliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4342498/nathanoliver)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60641983/9560245), it is not a safe operation and it **should not** be used in the modern C++ APIs. However, if you need to port the old already included C API within the existing C++ project, the following dirty hack could be used:

```cpp
union generalized_funtion_pointer_t
{
  void (*fp)(int*); // EXAMPLE
  void (*vp)(void*); // EXAMPLE
};
/* ... */
generalized_funtion_pointer_t gfp;
gfp.fp = exact_function_pointer;
some_c_struct->void_arg_function_pointer = gfp.vp;
```

**NOTE**: This hack can override some compilers and static analyzers like `clang-tidy`, but it is NOT SAFE in nature. It should be used ONLY in cases when you know that the **exact sizes** of the function pointers are **identical** and moreover, the **exact total sizes** of the argument lists of the functions on the given platform are also **identical**!

Comment: Like this should be worst. Reading from inactive union member in cpp is undefined behaviour.  Atleast most compilers will allow a reinterpret_cast.